Invalid Podfile file: no implicit conversion of nil into String react-native
When I run the pod install method in the ios folder in my React-Native project, I get the following error.
I used expo in this project. I run the Expo prebuild command successfully.
Afterwards, when I want to run the expo run:ios command, it wants to install cocoapods, but it is not successful.
I go to the ios directory and run pod install and I get the error I mentioned.
I tried the methods I found on GitHub, stackoverflow and many form pages.
But there was no solution.
I logged all my lines one by one in the podfile.
All lines are worth it.
I would be very happy if you could help.
i have a macbook 2020 m1 and macOS Sequoia.
I also tried this by creating a new project outside of my existing project, but it still didn't work.
Could my problem be related to the operating system or processor version?
I tried all the solutions I came across during my research, but I still can't figure it out.
I cannot build my project because the pod-install command does not work.
Kind regards.
[!] Invalid Podfile file: no implicit conversion of nil into String.

from /Users/sercan/Desktop/react/Veti/ios/Podfile:44
use_react_native!(

:path => config[:reactNativePath]

IOS: Invalid `Podfile` file: no implicit conversion of nil into String i try this,
IOS: Invalid `Podfile` file: no implicit conversion of nil into String i try this,
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/77363 i try this,
https://openvidu.discourse.group/t/various-error-building-on-ios/4975 i try this,
https://docs.expo.dev/bare/installing-expo-modules/ i try this,
https://docs.expo.dev/bare/installing-expo-modules/ i try this,
https://github.com/launchdarkly/ruby-server-sdk/issues/196 i try this,
